# Able to ping localhost, but cannot connect via my browser

Tags: ping, localhost, wamp

I've seen similar questions, but couldn't find any answers for my problem.

I'm using Windows 7 and Wamp for website development, and it was working fine until a couple of days ago. Now it won't let me connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1. My hosts file was missing, so I made a new one with the line "127.0.0.1 localhost".

I'm able to ping localhost and 127.0.0.1 no problem. I used netstat and confirmed that Wamp is using port 80.  Wamp says it's online. I have this error message in my Apache error log:

> (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you can try:

1. Execute `netsh winsock reset`.
2. Add `::1 localhost` to your `hosts` file (loopback for IPv6).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, any ideas what caused this problem all the sudden?

Comment: Your winsock catalog got modified somehow, but I can't tell you how or why.

Comment: Also, I just found out that Windows 7 handles loopback internally, so the `localhost` entries in your `hosts` file are obsolete.